# How to reload order summary section on payment page in Magento 2

Tags: magento2

I need to reload order summary section on selecting the payment method in magento 2

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please add more details what you coded and tried. Your question comes under "Low Quality Posts" and will be deleted in the absence of clarity so i request you to add complete and more details. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Create a file called `requirejs-config.js` within your module-theme folder (don't do this in vendor files).

In there add:

```
var config = {
   map: {
    '*': {
        custom:'Magento_Theme/js/custom',
    }
  }
};
```

Then create a file called `custom.js` under `module-theme/web/js` (Again not in your vendor files). And in there add:

```
define([
'jquery',
'Magento_Checkout/js/action/get-totals',
'Magento_Customer/js/customer-data'
 ], function ($, getTotalsAction, customerData) {
    $(document).ready(function(){

        var deferred = $.Deferred();
        getTotalsAction([], deferred);
    });
});
```

This should refresh the cart page when the page loads. If you want this to happen at a certain point just listen for a change event such as:

```
$(document).on('change', 'input[name$="[qty]"]', function(){
    var deferred = $.Deferred();
    getTotalsAction([], deferred);
});
```

Hope this helps